# Efficient way to manipulate large powers of two

Tags: java, math, bit-shift, largenumber

The most efficient way to code powers of two is by bit shifting of integers.

`1 << n` gives me `2^n`

However, if I have a number that is larger than the largest value allowed in an `int` or a `long`, what can I use to efficiently manipulate powers of 2?

(I need to be able to perform addition, multiplication, division and modulus operations on the number)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
BigInteger hugeNumber = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(n);
```

This is the result when n=1000,

```
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
```

Answer (score 3):

What operations do you need to perform on your "powers of two"?  If it's only division and multiplication, for example, you can just keep the `log2` of the powers of two in question, and use subtraction and addition on them instead.  Without knowing what *kinds* of "manipulate" you want, it's impossible to give good suggestions on how to *efficiently* "manipulate";-).

Comment: Sorry I left that out of the question, I need to perform addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and modulus

Comment: @bguiz, then you need BigInteger, as other answers mentioned.

Comment: @bguiz If you need to perform addition etc. then you're not actually working with powers of two. You just want a library for working with big numbers. So I'm left wondering why you didn't ask for that in the first place.

Comment: @user207442 : because I want something that handle large numbers AND do bit shifting (for powers of two). @ZZ Coder's answer fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

Easy: `long` :-)

If you don't mind floating-point, `double` can exactly represent all powers of 2 up to 2^1023.

Otherwise, it depends on what kind of "manipulation" you're doing.

Comment: @dan04 : I want to avoid floating point, also 'long' is not large enough. I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is what you need.

It has `mod`, `shiftLeft`, `shiftRight`, and of course `add`, `multiply`, `subtract` and `divide`. It's an immutable type (ala `String`), so perhaps it's not the ultimate most efficient way of doing things, but unless you've provably identified it as a performance problem, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be accurate?

Otherwise you can represent is as a long multiplied by an two to the power of an int.

Example:

x = 15 * 2^123